# How to show Current Date as Current Date ending at 3:00:00AM in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task that I need to show the current date time as ending at 3:00:00 AM at current date. For example, GETDATE() returns the current date time when executes. I need to show it as 9/5/2019 3:00:00 AM instead. Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @END_SHIFT AS DATETIME
SET @END_SHIFT = '06:00:00 AM'

SELECT 
NUMBER_ID, 
GETDATE()              AS CURRENT_DT,
GETDATE() - @END_SHIFT AS END_SHIFT_DATE
FROM table
```

My issue when running this is it does not return as ending at 3:00:00AM. Please let me know your direction.

Thanks,
H

Comment: If you want to store time of day use the `time` type, not `datetime`. As for the request, it's unusual to say the least. GetDate() is GetDate(). Why should it return some fixed value? If you want to use a fixed value set a variable or store it in a field

Comment: Do you also report the time shifted by 3 hours, or only the date?

Comment: SQL Server is good for showing you what's in the database. It's not usually preferred for developing complete applications. The best approach might be to `select number_id, getdate() as current_dt from table` and let the application (which could be a web app, a Perl script, a C# console app, whatever) display whatever it needs to display from that.

In other words, I'm not sure you have a SQL problem here.

Comment: @Tim, needed time ending at 3:00am from current date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of an odd request for sure but you could simply use DATEADD.

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, 3, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a "hard" time, one option is to use `format()`

**Example**

```
Select format(GetDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd 03:00')
```

**Returns**

```
2019-09-05 03:00
```

Comment: But this isn't a datetime; it's a string. :)